# How to sum XML node value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to sum xml node values, but luck is not favouring, please help.

```
select 
    animals_quantity.value('data(/AnimalsAddData/Quantity/@value)','int') 
from 
    tbl_animals
```

Comment: Show us a sample of the XML !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a very easy solution for it.

```
SELECT  sum(CAST(CAST(CAST(animals_quantity AS XML) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS INT)) as total from tbl_animals
```

Answer (score 1):

Take values from node and pass them to SUM aggregate:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '
<AnimalsAddData>
    <Quantity value="4" />
    <Quantity value="1" />
    <Quantity value="10" />
    <Quantity value="200" />
</AnimalsAddData>'

SELECT SUM(N.value('.', 'int'))
FROM @xml.nodes('/AnimalsAddData/Quantity/@value') T(N)
```

Make sure you include sample data.